# Facebook Graph API Caching

Tags: php, facebook, api, codeigniter, caching

Im working with the facebook graph API from inside CodeIgniter, the only problem is - its so damn slow to work and i was wondering if it would be possible to somehow cache the response from the graph servers on my own webserver somehow?

TO give you an indication of what i mean im making 1 graph API call for each record from the database(getting the number of likes for analytics) in my model, each record from the database is a single page on my site so you can imagine what that does for the performance of my app...

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's just like any other cache file. You save the JSON response as a file and check the `filemtime()` against `time()`. Only hit the graph API if your cache file is old.

Comment: are filemtime and time() graph API/SDK functions or are they PHP functions?

More importantly im using [link](https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-facebook) to talk to the graph API if time and filemtime are PHP SDK functions do these exist in there?

Comment: They are PHP functions. `filemtime()` is the timestamp of when a file was last modified. `time()` is the current timestamp. For example if you only want to hit the graph API once every hour, you'd create a simple if: `if((time() - filemtime($my_fbgraph_cache)) < 3600){ /* include($my_fbgraph_cache) */}else{ /* fetch graph API and rewrite cache, and display */}`

Comment: AllenWebguy thank you so much for that info about filemtime() and time(). I actually built that into the facebook library for my the framework im using and contributed it back - you can find the code here: https://github.com/lenswipe/codeigniter-facebook

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to cache data. You could use Redis, Mongo, Memcached, you could store it as a file on disk, you could even write it to a SQL database. Facebook's API Terms of Service prohibit the permanent storage of such data, however, so be wary of that and make sure your cache expires or is temporary in some fashion.

Comment: what if my cache ends up not being temporary(ill do my level best) but do facebook have a way to tell?

Comment: No, they'd have to investigate it by hand. So if you're making a ton of calls and it's not obvious that you're storing that stuff permanently, you're probably ok.